# How much volt and amps would be in this CT circuit?

Tags: voltage, current, transformer

[image]

1. How many amps would be in **Is**?
2. How many volts is **Vs**?
3. Does that voltage **depend** on te number of turns like current?
4. Can I operate a 24VAC or DC relay from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How many amps would be in Is?*

Without a burden resistor on the output of the secondary there is zero amps

> *How many volts is Vs?*

This cannot be determined with knowledge of the core material. If there was a proper burden resistor, this can be determined.

> *Does that voltage depend on te number of turns like current?*

The voltage depends on number of turns and the burden resistor.

> *Can I operate a 24VAC or DC relay from it?*

Usually not or even hardly ever - the point here is that the burden resistor is typically a few ohms of resistance in order to prevent the core from magnetically saturating AND, the output voltage produced is around a volt RMS.

Comment: Thank you, I added a question (4). Can I operate a 24VAC or DC relay? 
 Would a relay be considered as a burden resistor?

Comment: No, a relay wouldn't be considered as a burden resistor. Burden resistors come in all values but are typically a few ohms and the voltage that is produced across them is a few hundred milli-volts typically. There are exceptions with big CTs on large power feeds but, in general, you won't have the ability to drive a relay.

Comment: @Shaydzmi Of course, you could operate a relay using some amplification, though. Use an instrumentation amplifier to isolate and amplify the signal and a comparator to determine whether it's above the threshold you want the relay to actuate at, and then drive the relay coil from that with an appropriate driver circuit.

Comment: **Thank you,** @Hearth : Can you give me an example of an appropriate driver circuit considering the values given above ?

Comment: @Shaydzmi I think that's a different question entirely, and I'm not sure it's on-topic for the site since it's a "design this for me" question. Try doing some research yourself first into it, and then ask about anything you don't understand.